# MS SQL Server : primary keys, auto increment, and insert into failing

Tags: sql-server

I have this code I am converting from MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "odds_soccer" 
(
    "id" INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    "checked" DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    "bookmaker" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    "gametime" DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    "team1" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    "team2" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    "odds_1" FLOAT NOT NULL ,
    "odds_x" FLOAT NOT NULL ,
    "odds_2" FLOAT NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO "odds_soccer" ("id", "checked", "bookmaker", "gametime", "team1", "team2", "odds_1", "odds_x", "odds_2") 
VALUES (null, '2017-03-02 16:00:00', 'example.com', '2017-03-02 04:30:00', 'MYTEAMA', 'MYTEAMB', '3.15', '3.15', '2.70');
```

Only problem is... It barfs that I can not use null for inserting which is fair enough...

But how do I insert a record where *I simply want the ID to auto increment*.

I have tried various variations - all failing - I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: MS SQL is SQL-Server, not MySQL. Please use the correct tag in the future.

Comment: As Barmar said, please update the tag and the title of this question. Your question is for MySQL.

Comment: If I tagged it MySQL that was an error. Should have been MS SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct approach is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE "odds_soccer" (
    "id" INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ,
    "checked" DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    "bookmaker" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    "gametime" DATETIME NOT NULL ,
    "team1" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    "team2" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    "odds_1" FLOAT NOT NULL ,
    "odds_x" FLOAT NOT NULL ,
    "odds_2" FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

And this way your `id` field will be auto incremented every time you insert a new record in the table.
Note that if you have id field auto incremented you don't have to specify it in your `insert` statement.

```
INSERT INTO "odds_soccer" 
(
  "checked",
  "bookmaker",
  "gametime",
  "team1",
  "team2",
  "odds_1",
  "odds_x",
  "odds_2"
) 
VALUES (
  '2017-03-02 16:00:00',
  'example.com',
  '2017-03-02 04:30:00',
  'MYTEAMA',
  'MYTEAMB',
  '3.15',
  '3.15',
  '2.70'
);
```

[Link to documentation(IDENTITY)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Comment: It works now! no sure what the problem was yesterday - but tried it again today and it works. Answer accepted